# Error on user profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I noticed there is error on user profile page. E.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters you have "{ Member since today } else { Member for 5 years, 11 months }" instead of just "Member for 5 years, 11 months".